# SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException => unknown error (code 14): Could not open database (Android 6.0)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, root

Following is working on many thousands of devices but recently I got following errors, twice, both from android 6.0, so it may be related to the new android version:

```
RootUtils.copyDatabase(path, pathApp);
if (new File(pathApp).exists())
{
    L.d(this, "Database copied!"); // <= this is called, so copying file succeeds!!!

    SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(pathApp, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    final Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from contacts", new String[0]); // <= this line throws the exception
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    ....
}
```

**Log/Exception**

```
c.m.s.utils.RootUtils   [RootUtils-91]  copyDatabase: true
c.m.s.networks.utils.Util   [FUtil-105] Database copied!
c.m.s.networks.utils.Util   [FUtil-185] unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:207)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:191)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:806)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:791)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
    ...
```

**My copy function is following**:

```
public final static boolean copyDatabase(String pathSource, String pathTarget) throws IOException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException, RootDeniedException
{
    Shell shell = RootTools.getShell(true);
    Command command = new Command(0,
            "su\n",
            "rm " + pathTarget + "\n",
            "cat " + pathSource + " > " + pathTarget + "\n",
            "chown root.root " + pathTarget + "\n",
            "chmod 777 " + pathTarget + "\n");
    command = shell.add(command);
    int exitCode = command.getExitCode();
    while (!command.isFinished()) {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    }
    shell.close();
    boolean success = exitCode == -1 && command.isFinished();
    L.d(RootUtils.class, "copyDatabase: " + success);
    return success;
}
```

**Edit: My new copy function that even sets the Owner/Group to my apps process - only got one feedback yet, but seems to not solve the problem**

```
public final static boolean copyDatabase(String ownAppDatabase, String pathSource, String pathTarget) throws IOException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException, RootDeniedException
{
    Shell shell = RootTools.getShell(true);

    boolean getRealUser = true;
    String owner = null;
    String group = null;
    if (getRealUser)
    {
        final  StringHolder lsResult = new StringHolder("");
        Command lsCommand = new Command(0,
                "su\n",
                "ls -ld " + ownAppDatabase + "\n")
        {
            public void commandOutput(int id, String line) {
                super.commandOutput(id, line);
                lsResult.set(line);
            }

        };
        lsCommand = shell.add(lsCommand);
        int lsExitCode = lsCommand.getExitCode();
        while (!lsCommand.isFinished()) {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        }

        L.d(RootUtils.class, "ls exit code: " + lsExitCode);
        L.d(RootUtils.class, "ls result: " + lsResult.get());

        String[] parts = lsResult.get().split("\\s+");
        if (parts.length > 3)
        {
            owner = parts[1];
            group = parts[2];
        }
    }

    if (owner == null || group == null)
    {
        L.d(RootUtils.class, "owner or group is NULL!");
        getRealUser = false;
    }
    else
        L.d(RootUtils.class, "owner=" + owner + " | group=" + group);

    Command command = new Command(0,
            "su\n",
            "rm " + pathTarget + "\n",
            "cat " + pathSource + " > " + pathTarget + "\n",
            "chown " + (getRealUser ? (owner + "." + group + " ") : "chown root.root ") + pathTarget + "\n",
            "chmod 777 " + pathTarget + "\n");
    command = shell.add(command);
    int exitCode = command.getExitCode();
    while (!command.isFinished()) {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    }
    shell.close();
    boolean success = exitCode == -1 && command.isFinished();
    L.d(RootUtils.class, "copyDatabase: " + success);
    return success;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the only solution I found out (it should work on all older devices as well):

**Dump the database!**

Copying the database does not work, reading the database either. Probably because the database is opened by another process. But dumping the database works. You can dump a single table as well, here's an example that works on all devices:

```
String dump = pathSQLite3 + " " + pathDB + " \".dump '" + tablename + "'\"\n";
```

Only drawback, you have to add the sqlite executables to your app and you have to find out, which architecture the target device has so that you know which sqlite executable you can use...

But at least this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue right after updating to Android 6.0 when trying to open an SQLite database stored on the internal storage.

It was caused by the new permissions model of Marshmallow.

As a workaround I had to go to my app's "App Info" Page of the System Settings and grant the permission for Storage access.

Comment: Thanks, but that sounds as it was another problem. I'm not accessing internal storage but the apps own storage folder (I'm copying the file to my apps folders)... I experienced, that `SQLiteDatabase` can only work with own files... But I'll check that though...

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there - also need to do this after chmod: "chcon u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 ".